# Flutter Navigate Screens via Route & Drawer: Use Pop, PushNamed or PushReplacementNamed

Tags: routes, flutter, assets

I am using Flutter with Routing to few screens. Every screen has a drawer that helps to navigate to the different screen.
My question is: 
What is the best practice for routing screens in my situation?

1. Navigator.pop followed by Navigator.pushNamed("/aScreen")
2. Navigator.pushNamed("/aScreen") without pop
3. Navigator.pop followed by Navigator.pushReplacementNamed("/aScreen")
4. Navigator.pushReplacementNamed("/aScreen") without pop

What are the differences?

Another question, I am experiencing exceptions that the AssetImages is not loading because of null. It loads fine when app launches but after a few mins, even without any activities (like remain on a screen), one by one, the exception will suddenly pop up, crashing the app.

This is the error:

```
compiler message: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Getter not found: 'pubspec'.
compiler message: pubspec
compiler message: ^^^^^^^
compiler message: org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: The getter 'pubspec' isn't defined for the class '#lib1::PlatformAssetBundle'.
compiler message: Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'pubspec'.
compiler message: pubspec
compiler message: ^
flutter: Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: assets/bar.jpg
```

I suspect that the asset images were disposed off, creating this exception but not sure what is actually going on..

Comment: I guess you added the assets to pubspec.yaml correctly?

Comment: Yes, like I said, everything is displaying ok until a mins later. And, only when it is under debug mode.

Comment: Your issue and description are completely unrelated